# when to cancel nsurlconnection in a uinavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, nsurlconnection

Can someone please explain to me why the viewcontroller dealloc method doesn't get called when I press the backbutton on a uinavigationcontroller?

I want to properly cancel my nsurlconnection so it doesn't try to display a popup and crash because its delegate is no longer valid.

My NSURLConnection is initialized as follows:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [ [ NSURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.url.com" ], string1, string2 ] ] ];

connection = [ [ NSURLConnection alloc ] initWithRequest: request delegate: self ];

[ request release ];
```

I release the connection in connectionDidFinishLoading and didFailWithError but I want to cancel and release the connection when the user presses the back button. The most logical place seems to be the dealloc method but I suspect this doesn't get called because the connection is retaining the viewcontroller.

What is the best way to make sure that a connection is cancelled when the back button is pressed? I don't want to use viewwilldissapear because I present another viewcontroller modally which should not be a reason for cancelling (unless the same problem would occur in the modal viewcontroller, pop-up+crash).

Comment: `NSURLConnection`does retain its delegate when it is initialized and releases it when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled.

Comment: How do I deal with a timeout? The user will have popped the viewcontroller before the timeout popup is presented. This leads to a crash when the timeout eventually occurs.. :-(

Comment: "...crash because its delegate is no longer valid". How can it be no longer valid if `NSURLConnection` retains its delegate ensuring it is not `dealloc`ated (unless it's over-released somewhere else)?

Comment: you are right, it is still valid. But why does my application crash when I'm not in the viewcontroller which created the connection and I dismiss the 'timeout' popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use viewwilldisappear. Even if you present another modal view controller no problem. And just do like this within ur viewwilldisappear. Declare ur connection object in .h file then

```
if(urConnection){
  [urconnection Cancel];
  [urconnection release];
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it is the most useful. In the end I solved my problem by not displaying any pop-ups in connectiondidfailwitherror unless the viewcontroller is currently visible. if it is not visible I just release all the remaining memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is better to release the connection object in dealloc method or connectionDidFinishLoading delegate. But I dont think its of use to release the connection on back button since once the back button is pressed the object get destroyed itself and calls dealloc method. So, use dealloc method to place code to release connection.

Comment: I want to release the connection in the dealloc method but it never gets called when, for example, there is a connection timeout after x minutes. Only when the timeout occurs does the dealloc get called, but by then it is too late since I'm in a different viewcontroller. I guess everybody needs to cancel their pending connections when the viewcontroller gets popped (assuming you set the delegate to self for the connection)?